# React Native Buttons don't work when adding FacebookAds from Expo

Tags: android, facebook, button, react-native, expo

I've got a problem with my React Native application. Every time I add the `<Facebook.BannerView />` component from `expo` my `<Button />` components from `react-native-elements` stop working.

Example:

My buttons work fine with this implementation:

```
render() {
  const { containerStyle, adContainerStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={containerStyle}>

        <Button
          title="Button"
          onPress={() => console.log('Button pressed')}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={adContainerStyle}>
        <Text>Bottom Banner Ad goes here</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = {
  containerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ddd'
  },
  adContainerStyle: {
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
};
```

But when I replace my `<Text>Bottom Banner Ad goes here</Text>` component with this:

```
<FacebookAds.BannerView
  placementId="328225604270934_328227207604107"
  type="standard"
  onPress={() => console.log('Banner ad clicked')}
  onError={err => console.log('Banner Ad Error', err)}
/>
```

The `<Button />` stops working.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out that the `adContainerStyle` was conflicting with the `Facebook.BannerView />` component.

I solved my problem by removing all the style attributes from the `adContainerStyle` except the `backgroundColor` attribute like this:

```
adContainerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#ccc',
}
```

**EDIT:**

I realized that this was a recurring problem. For some reason, removing the `<Facebook.BannerView />` component, running the app (so it works) then adding the component back in fixed it every time.

A bit annoying and hopefully it gets fixed on it's own soon but this is a suitable workaround for now.

Comment: When this happens for me, Expo starts using 600% of my CPU as well. The first time I tried removing and adding the component it worked like a charm. Now it seems to not matter what I do, if the component is present, no buttons will work and the ad doesn't even show.

Comment: I did this back before they implemented Admob support. So I'd recommend you go that route if you have a choice.